# Error 404 when loading css in static folder

Tags: python, css, django, static, http-status-code-404

I have created CSS files in a folder static and currently I'm getting this error 404 when its trying to load the page and no css is being recognised.

my folders are

```
DEMOPROJECT
    -DEMOAPP
     --migrations
     --templates
        ---DEMOAPP
               -----homepage.html
            ----base.html
    -DEMOPROJECT
         --static
             ---css
                ----NavMENU.css
         --settings.py
         --urls.py
```

My terminal is this

```
(venv) C:\Users\jferguson\PycharmProjects\WebP1\DEMOPROJECT>
```

I have tried different settings that every other person has asked. None seem to be working.

THIS is in the urls.py file for static folder.

```
urlpatterns = [
                  re_path(r'^admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
                  re_path(r'^documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),
                  re_path(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),
              ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is in settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

EDIT
My homepage_html has this at the top.

```
{% extends "../base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load wagtailcore_tags wagtailimages_tags %}
{% block body_class %}home{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute collectstatic command as follow

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

In your settings.py file add:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') 
STATIC_URL = '/static/' 
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'your_project_name/static') ]
```

In your case :

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'DEMOPROJECT/static') ]
```

Comment: @Joeld does your Html template loaded?

Comment: then in template  have you loaded static files as like {% load static%}?

Comment: I have indeed. The problem doesn't seem to be that though. Its more just the locating of the static files.

Comment: You have do something like:
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'DEMOPROJECT/static')
]
Hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

try this `python manage.py collectstatic` and restart your server. Hope so this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Meha Parekh for the answer!

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') 
STATIC_URL = '/static/' 
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'DEMOPROJECT/static')]
```

This works ^ instead of the following code in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```